# Setting specific values of a list : LINQ

Tags: linq

I have a listA that contains objects with the following properties `x`,`y`,`z`.
also i have another `listB` that contain similar objects.

Now i want to select all the objects present in `listA` and at the same time set the `z` property of those objects whose `A.x==B.x && A.y==B.y`

```
List<Point> listA = //list of objects
List<Point> listB = //list of points
```

How do i do this?

Comment: Can you post what you've tried? You can start here http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b (There is a similar page for VB.NET)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify `listA` with respect to your needs you can use following LINQ:

```
listA.ForEach(pA => pA.Z = listB.Where(pB => pA.X == pB.X && pA.Y == pB.Y)
                                .DefaultIfEmpty(pA)
                                .First()
                                .Z);
```

Then you can simply select all `listA` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if following is what you want:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class A
{
    public double X {get; set;}
    public double Y {get; set;}
    public double Z {get; set;}
}

class B 
{
    public double X {get; set;}
    public double Y {get; set;}
    public double Z {get; set;}
}

public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        var listA = new List<A>
        {
            new A {X = 1, Y = 2, Z = 3}
        };

        var listB = new List<B>
        {
            new B {X = 1, Y = 2, Z = 3}
        };

        var result = from a in listA
                     from b in listB
                     select new A
                     {
                        X = a.X,
                        Y = a.Y,
                        Z = (a.X == b.X && a.Y == b.Y) == true ? 0 : 10
                     };


        foreach(var r in result)
            Console.WriteLine(
                String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", r.X, r.Y, r.Z));

        // output: 1, 2, 0 because a.X == b.X && a.Y == b.Y

    }   
}
```

So `Z` is set to 0 based on `a.X == b.X && a.Y == b.Y`. If this condition wasn't satisfied, it would be set to 10. You can obviously decide what `Z` is set to yourself.

Comment: It will select new list, and not change existing one.

Comment: I wasn't entirely sure if OP wanted to select a new list or update the existing `listA`...